# Difficulty with regular expression syntax in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I am using the this regular expression to find all occurrences of `INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL`:

```
\bINT\s*IDENTITY\s*\(1,\s*1\)\s*NOT\s*NULL\b
```

A sample of where it is in the whole context is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    [col]                INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [col2]               INT      NOT NULL,
    [col3]               BIT      NOT NULL,
    [col4]               BIT      NOT NULL,
    [col5]               DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([col] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, PAD_INDEX = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF)
);
```

But the regular expression above does not find anything. When I try it online using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/), Gskinner, or [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/), it works.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has its own specific regex flavour - for example there is no `\b` (for word boundary, I presume), so using it will not work.

I suggest reading up on Regular Expressions (Visual Studio) [2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) / [2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) for the syntax.

Comment: The question is tagged with Visual Studio 2010. The reference describes Visual Studio 2012 (at least as of today), not Visual Studio 2010: "In Visual Studio 2010 and earlier versions, Visual Studio used custom regular expression syntax in the Find and Replace windows. "

Comment: [Regular Expressions for Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Thanks for the correction and link. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
:b+INT:b+IDENTITY:b+(1,:b*1):b+NOT:b+NULL
```

Comment: This was close, but I believe you need to escape the ( and ) characters or it treats it as a group.

Comment: @Xaisoft good to know. I didn't test it much I was hoping he would run with that.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following expression:

```
INT:b+IDENTITY:b+\(1,:b*1\):b+NOT:bNULL
```